# Using Github on another computer

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have been working on computer A and would like to work on one of my Github projects on another computer (lets call it computer B), but I can't figure out how to import it. Right now I'm trying to do

git clone ssh://github.com/username/projectname.git on computer B

but it says permission denied (publickey).

What should I do here? Should I generate an SSH key on computer B and upload it to my github account? So each computer has its own SSH key to connect to github? is that what i should do? How do I generate an SSH key?

Thanks - git/github has been a pain for me so far, and I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. Generate a second SSH key on your other computer, and add its pubkey via the GitHub account settings interface. Then you'll be able to clone from there.

That's the way the public key authentication system works - each machine you want to give access has its own key; that allows you to grant and revoke access for each machine independently, rather than having to copy a key around from machine to machine (potentially making it vulnerable to interception in the process).

Comment: should this be a dsa or rsa? how should i name them on github? does github just compare all keys, so naming doesn't matter?

Comment: Naming doesn't matter, it's purely for your own memory. Key type shouldn't either; I believe GitHub will accept either.

Comment: I'm getting this error message when I do ssh -vT git@github.com:


debug1: Offering public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 151
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Offering public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 435
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/identity
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: ok, it might be working now. for reference: https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign

Comment: Does this mean if someone uses the same computer they will be able to push to my repo if they know which repo to try?

Comment: Depends on if they have access to the key file. Normally keys are also protected with a password that they would need to know.